# fileReader.readAsText() throwing 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I'm trying to read a CSV or Excel file in order to convert it to table. 
For now I just created a class in order to read the input file:

The input is:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="file_upload">
```

For now I just created a class in order to read the input file:

```
 class InputReader_tiqet{

    constructor(input_id) {
        this.inputId=input_id;
        this.filetoLoad=document.getElementById("file_upload").files[0];
    }   

    readFileData(){
        this.filetoLoad = document.getElementById(this.inputId).files[0];
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent){
            this.fileData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;

        };

        fileReader.readAsText(this.fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
    }

    getData(){
        return this.fileData;
    }


}
```

I run it as it follows:

```
inputReader_object= new InputReader_tiqet("file_upload");

 $("#file_upload").on('change', function(){
            inputReader_object.readFileData();
            //clean input field
            this.val("");
});
```

When the input file changes I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
```

Comment: problem solved:
this.filetoLoad instead of this.fileToLoad. Is that an easy way of find this type of errors?

Comment: You mean typo's? Any competent IDE and even most text editors should highlight inconsistencies such as `let load = 3; var x = laod + 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved: this.filetoLoad instead of this.fileToLoad.